# LWC How do I get the RecordType DeveloperName from getObjectInfo or from the passed object?

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type, lwc-wire-adapter

In my Lightning Web Component I am passed the accountId and recordtypeId amongst a few other fields. I need to determine which recordtype the account is in order to display different parts in the component's html. This part gets me the recordtypeIDS if I pass it the Name, but I want it the other way around. I have the Id, but need the name.

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
objectInfo;
get recordTypeId() {
// Returns a map of record type Ids
  const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
  return Object.keys(rtis).find(
    rti => rtis[rti].name === 'myAccountRecordType'
  );
}
```

I tried accessing the RecordTypeDeveloperName from the account passed in, but couldn't find a way to do that - if I could, that would save me having to look it up. Is that possible? It didn't like me adding the *.RecordType.DeveloperName.value* to the fields.

```
const FIELDS = [
"Account.Id",
"Account.FirstName",
"Account.LastName",
"Account.PersonEmail",
"Account.RecordType",
"Account.isPersonAccount"
];

//Account variables
@track fname;
@track lname;
@track aemail;
@track aid;
@track arectype;
@track arectypeid;
@track isPerson;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: FIELDS })
wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
if (data) {
  this.record = data;
  this.aid = this.record.fields.Id.value;
  this.fname = this.record.fields.FirstName.value;
  this.lname = this.record.fields.LastName.value;
  this.aemail = this.record.fields.PersonEmail.value;
  this.arectype = this.record.fields.RecordTypeId.value;
  this.isPerson = this.record.fields.isPersonAccount.value;
  this.error = undefined;
} else if (error) {
  this.error = error;
  this.record = undefined;
}
}
```

In my HTML I'm trying to determine whether the Account is a Person type or not. Using IsPersonAccount doesn't work, and I don't know how else to work out the type of account.

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control slds-m-around_medium">
  <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Account">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-box">
      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Name"></lightning-output-field>
        <template if:true={isPersonAccount}>
          <lightning-output-field field-name="PersonEmail"></lightning-output-field>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </lightning-record-view-form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The field for record type id is `'Account.RecordTypeId'` and NOT `"Account.RecordType"` in `FIELDS`.
2. In HTML you should be using class [fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields) and not something else like `isPersonAccount` which is not even defined. Do not get confused with class field vs object field. You defined `isPerson` as class field and object field is `isPersonAccount`.

Here is the simplified version:

HTML:

```
    <div>recordType - {recordType}</div>
    <div>isPerson - {isPerson}</div>
```

JS:

```
const FIELDS = [ 'Account.Name', 'Account.RecordTypeId', 'Account.isPerson' ];

export default class Poc extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    recordId = '0010K00002IgBhRQAV';
    //Account variables
    @track name;
    @track recordType;
    @track isPerson;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data;
            this.name = this.record.fields.Name.value;
            this.recordType = this.record.fields.RecordTypeId.value;
            this.isPerson = this.record.fields.isPerson.value;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this use case. I used to try getObjectInfo but failed.

In my workaround, I retrieve the Name, developerName, Id from RecordType sObject.

For example:

```
select Name, Id, DeveloperName from RecordType where Id = :recordTypeId
```

Or you could just soql the object's RecordTypeInfo by:

```
select Id, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name, RecordType.DeveloperName from Custom_Object__c where RecordTypeID = :recorcTypeId
```

both cases need to write an Apex method and wire the method in your Js file.